# How do I find middle range with normal distribution?

Tags: statistics

I am currentLy reading my textbook there is an example that I cant understand. Can someone explain to me the hint given to solve it?

Q.

Verbal SAT scores follow normal(430,100) distribution. What is the middle range of scores encompassing $50\%$ of the population?

Hint.

$$P(430-y \le X \le 430 +y) = 0.5$$

Can someone explain to me why it is $430-y$ and $430+y$? What does that do?

Comment: The normal with mean $430$ is symmetric about $x=430$. (Draw a bell-shaped curve symmetric about $x=430$.) We want an interval *symmetric* about $430$ that encompasses half the population.

Comment: I am lost about how it would look like visually when you say half the population on interval symmetric about 430.